# Registration MR and CT images in 3D Slicer

Tags: python, 3d, registration, slicers, tomography-reconstruction

I want to overlap the MR and CT images in 3D Slicer, but since the CT image I have is cut from the lower part of the nose, many structures in the MR image do not correspond to the CT, so the registration process cannot be performed completely. What should I do? What do you suggest?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoVia.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1i8K.png)

Comment: You need to use one of the advanced existing registration methods. Possibly non-rigid, but for the head rigid methods should work. I know of elastix and niftyreg, but other exist.

Answer (score 0):

Elastix works. General registration brains work as well. If not satisfied you can fine tune using  transforms